# How can make the md-tabs length take all parent length

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I have the following tabs inside my project but my problem that the tabs is not cover all the space

```
<fieldset class="form-group userEditGrid"  ng-if="proj.checkEditProjectPanelCriteria(proj.selectionRow)" style="top:42%; height: 55%; !important">
    <legend  style="color:#d77509;font-weight:bold; border:0px; width:10%;" > {{proj.getMode()}}</legend>
        <div ng-cloak="" class="tabsdemoDynamicHeight">
            <md-content>
                <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom=""  md-selected="proj.selectedLevelTabs" >
                    <md-tab label="General Information" ng-disabled = "proj.isFireProtectionPanelOpen() || proj.isAddDocumentPanelOpen()">
                        <form name="editForm">
                            <md-content class="md-padding">
                                <div class="row" disable-all = "proj.ViewMode == 1">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error': editForm.projanyname.$dirty && editForm.projectname.$error.required }">
                                            <md-input-container class="md-block" >
                                                <label for="projectname">Project Name *</label> 
                                                <input type="text" name="projectname" id="projectname" class="form-control" ng-model="proj.copyProjectRow.projectName" required="">
                                                <span ng-show="editForm.projectname.$dirty && editForm.projectname.$error.required" class="help-block">project name is required</span>
                                            </md-input-container>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                           </md-content>
                        </form>
                    </md-tab>
                    <md-tab>
                      <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div class="row">
                            <jsp:include page="levels/level1.jsp" />
                        </div>
                      </md-content>
                    </md-tab>
                </md-tabs>
            </md-content>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

How can I make the length of the tabs take up all the space?

NOTE: I call this file form other jsp file

```
<div>
    <jsp:include page="editProject.jsp" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do to fill 100% height of the md-tab body:

First of all we need to create a CSS class to make first child of md-tab-content 100% height:

```
md-tab-content > div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then the structure of a tab must be like this:

```
<md-tab>
    <md-tab-label>Tab title label</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
            <div layout-fill layout="column">
                <p>This will be full height</p>
            </div>
    </md-tab-body>
</md-tab>
```

Note that we must use layout-fill on the container inside `<md-tab-body>` to make it grow with 100% height. If we need to have more children layouts inside our container we must use `layout="column"`to make them grow vertically and use `flex`attributes as we need our layout structure.

I hope this solve your problem! It's probably impossible to make `md-tab-body`content grow only using flex and not using CSS classes.